# Deleting element from view in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am working on a note-taking app.

I want my app to delete all checked radios on clicking the 'Remove' link. An insight into the code:

**HTML**:

```
<p>[ <a href='#/home'>Cancel</a> | <a href='#/home/edit' ng-click='remove()'>Remove</a> ]</p>
<table border='0'>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat='note in notes'>
      <td>
        <input type='radio' ng-model='note.rmv'></input>
      </td>
      <td>{{note.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('editCtrl', ['$scope', 'notes', function($scope, notes) {
  $scope.notes = notes.notes;
  $scope.remove = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.notes.length; ++i) {
      if ($scope.notes[i].rmv) {
        delete $scope.notes[i];
        notes.getLost($scope.notes[i]._id);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('notes', ['$http', function($http) {
  var t = {
    notes: []
  };
  t.getLost = function(id) {
    return $http.delete('/home/edit').success(function(data) {
      return t.getAll();
    });
  };
  return t;
};
```

What might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular element remove does not work ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663754/angular-element-remove-does-not-work)

Comment: How does `$scope.notes` suddenly change to `$notes.notes` ? Meaning that you first loop `$scope.notes` then in that loop you check `$notes.notes[i]`..

Comment: I don't think <input> has an end </input> tag either

Comment: @Hardy It should be $scope.notes in the if loop

Comment: @FrankerZ I expect that the elements be removed from my MongoDB server. I'm editing to include the body of getLost() which calls an http request from a factory

Comment: @NitishKulshrestha yes i know it should be.. that's why i commented :)

Comment: your `getLost` is really lost.. :) read the angular docs.. you should rewrite whole thing..

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a lot of mistakes in your `code`, I think you should refactor your `code`. Also there's no necessity of delete the item in `Javascript`, you can delegate it all to your `back-end` since you already have the *function* to getAll `objects`.

See the `code` below to take it as example:

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('editCtrl', editCtrl)
    .factory('notes', notes);

  editCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'notes'];

  function editCtrl($scope, notes) {
    getAll(); // <- initialization of notes
    $scope.remove = remove;

    function getSuccess(response) {
      console.log('success');
    }

    function getError(response) {
      console.log('error');
    }

    function remove() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.notes.length; ++i) {
        if ($scope.notes[i].rmv) {
          notes.getLost($scope.notes[i]._id)
            .then(getSuccess)
            .catch(getError);
        }
      }
      fetchData();
    }

    function fetchData() {
      notes.getAll()
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.notes = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
          console.log('error');
        });
    }
  }

  notes.$inject = ['$http'];

  function notes($http) {
    var factory = {
      getAll: getAll,
      getLost: getLost
    };

    return factory;

    function getAll() {
      return $http.get('url_to_fetch');
    }

    function getLost(id) {
      // It should only return the promise, not more than that
      return $http.delete('/home/edit/' + id); // <- is this URL correct?
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: thanks, although it's part of a MEAN app and wouldn't make complete sense to you

Comment: Well, unfortunately I have to go ahead and say: even if anyone of us know your whole *application*, it's wrong in many parts.. by the way, modyfing the part of deletion make it works? If so, can you check it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
if($notes.notes[i].rmv) {
```

Should be:

```
if($scope.notes[i].rmv) {
```